# ord() function in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7

Trying to open a project from Python 2.7 on Python 3.6. I run into a problem with `ord()` function there.

Working with Python 2.7 is fine with `ord()` and I'm getting my outputting image file with the same picture. I mean, I can write bytes of infromation in the picture , I'm giving.

But as for Python 3.6 I tried not to call `ord()` and I'm getting a line with recording information instead of my real picture with the infromation, like it was with python 2.7.

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
textfile = open(sys.argv[1],'rb')
textstring = textfile.read()
textfile.close()
xval = 500
yval = int(len(textstring)/(xval*4) + 1)
im = Image.new('RGBA', (xval,yval), (0,0,0,0))
width = xval
height = yval
count = 0
for y in range (0,height):
    for x in range (0,width):
        if count == len(textstring) - 4:
            im.putpixel((x,y),(ord(textstring[count]),ord(textstring[count + 1]),ord(textstring[count + 2]),ord(textstring[count + 3])))
            break
        if count == len(textstring) - 3:
            im.putpixel((x,y),(ord(textstring[count]),ord(textstring[count + 1]),ord(textstring[count + 2]),0))
            break
        if count == len(textstring) - 2:
            im.putpixel((x,y),(ord(textstring[count]),ord(textstring[count + 1]),0,0))
            break
        if count == len(textstring) - 1:
            im.putpixel((x,y),(ord(textstring[count]),0,0,0))
            break
        im.putpixel((x,y),(ord(textstring[count]),ord(textstring[count + 1]),ord(textstring[count + 2]),ord(textstring[count + 3])))
        count += 4
im.save(sys.argv[2])
```

In python 3, I get an error ,using `ord()`:

> TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
>   im.putpixel((x,y),(ord(textstring[count]),ord(textstring[count + 1]),ord(textstring[count + 2]),ord(textstring[count + 3])))

I was trying to add `b` instead of `ord()` but it wasn't succesful.

For running a program need to add args: `python encryption.py inputfile image.png`
Can you give some advice ,how I should fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have a text file, yet you explicitly open it in **binary** mode:

```
textfile = open(sys.argv[1],'rb')
```

use

```
textfile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
```

to read it in text mode. When you read it in binary mode, you get `bytes` in Python 3; the elements of `bytes` are integers in range 0 .. 255, hence the error. Python 2 is so sloppy no one notices the difference until it is too late.